# Dask equivalent of pyspark lead and lag function

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, dask

Is it possible to receive in `dask` dataframe similar results which can be receive by `lag` or `lead` window functions at `pyspark`? I want to tranform following dataframe

```
    +-------+
    | value |
    +-------+
    | 1     |
    | 2     |
    | 3     |
    +-------+
```

to something like this

```
    +-------+------------+------------+
    | value | prev_value | next_value |
    +-------+------------+------------+
    | 1     | NaN        | 2          |
    | 2     | 1          | 3          |
    | 3     | 2          | NaN        |
    +-------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dask dataframe just mirrors the pandas interface. In this case the method you want is [shift](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.shift):

```
In [3]: import pandas as pd

In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(5)})

In [5]: import dask.dataframe as dd

In [6]: ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

In [7]: out = ddf.assign(prev_a=ddf.a.shift(1), next_a=ddf.a.shift(-1))

In [8]: out.compute()
Out[8]:
   a  prev_a  next_a
0  0     NaN     1.0
1  1     0.0     2.0
2  2     1.0     3.0
3  3     2.0     4.0
4  4     3.0     NaN
```

However, if you're trying to align rows to do some kind of windowed or rolling computation, you may be more interested in [map_overlap](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.map_overlap), which would be more performant.